# UIDatePicker Order Format

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios5, ios6

I am new to ios development  tried UIDatepicker format like day month date. I tried alot but not able to get, Can any one help ?

```
 NSDate *storedDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];
 storedDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"EE,MMMM dd"];

// add this check and set
if (storedDate == nil) {
    storedDate = [NSDate date];
}

[self.pickerView setDate:storedDate animated:NO];
```

[image]

i need the above image format

Answer (score 1):

First, get the saved date in string Format.

```
NSString *storedDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"DatePickerViewControllerselectedDate"];
```

Then get the format in which the date is stored so that you can convert it to date.

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
format.dateFormat=@"EEEE, MMMM dd";
```

Now you can convert the stored-date to date format and set in datepicker.

```
NSDate *sortedDateFormatted = [format dateFromString:storedDate];
[self.pickerView setDate:sortedDateFormatted animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the date format ryt, Just try this

```
  NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; 
  NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  format.dateFormat=@"EEEE, MMMM dd";
  NSString * dateStr = [[format stringFromDate:now] capitalizedString];
  NSDate *sortedDateFormatted = [format dateFromString:dateStr];
 [self.pickerView setDate:sortedDateFormatted animated:NO];
```

Comment: @ SampathKumar : above code  dateStr its comming correct format when is going to this line 
 NSDate *sortedDateFormatted = [format dateFromString:dateStr];
i am not get the Exact result. its showing time and minits